# How to display only rows of data that meet certain criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I display, on a separate sheet, only rows of data based on one column of that data meeting a certain criteria in Excel? There are at least 15 columns & 240 rows in the original data sheet and I need to display the entire rows of data if one cell in that row meets the criteria.

Comment: have you already tried pivot table? that should be a pretty nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not being a VB person I don't understand DeltaHotel's answer so I would brute force it with an IF statement on the target sheet.
Once I got one cell working I would copy it to each cell in the row and column.

U can ref cells on the orig sheet and diligently use relative/absolute formatting to get it right.

VB is more elegant if u understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Data Filter option (**Filter** from **Data** ribbon) to restrict the scope of your source sheet, then copy the entire sheet to the Target sheet. This could be wrapped in a small VBA module if you want to automate, and the module could dynamically create (or clear) the target sheet.

Something like the following code:

> ```
> ' clear the target sheet
> Sheets("Target Sheet").Select
> Cells.Select
> Selection.ClearContents
> Range("A1").Select
>
> ' go to source sheet
> Sheets("Source Sheet").Select
>
> ' filter as needed
> ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$500").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=100", _
>     Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=200"
>
> ' copy filtered rows to target
> Cells.Select
> Selection.Copy
> Sheets("Target Sheet").Select
> ActiveSheet.Paste
> Range("A1").Select
> Sheets("Source Sheet").Select
> Application.CutCopyMode = False
> Range("A1").Select
> ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$O$500").AutoFilter Field:=4
> ```

Put that code in a module, then you can run the code from the Developer ribbon (Macros) or you could assign to a button on your Ribbon or Quick Access toolbar if desired.